# Rigorous justification for "complex" change of variable in integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, fourier-analysis

Suppose that I have $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ i.i.d. $\sim $ $X$ and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ i.i.d. $\sim$ $Y$ for some continuous $X$ and $Y$. Consider the r.v.'s $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_jX_j$ and $\bar{Y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_jY_j$. First, the joint MGF for $(X,Y)$ can be written as
$$
M(t,u)=\exp{K(t,u)}=E[\exp(tX+uY)].
$$
Here $K$ denotes the joint CGF (the joint cumulant generating function). Then, I know enough to write the density $f_n$ of $(\bar{X},\bar{Y})$ as
$$
f_n(\bar{x},\bar{y})=\frac{n^2}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp[n(K(it,iu)-it\bar{x}-iu\bar{y})] \, dt \, du.\tag{$*$}
$$
My reading (source available if requested) says that I can write ($*$) as
$$
f_n(\bar{x},\bar{y})=\frac{n^2}{(2\pi i)^2}\int\int\exp[n(K(t,u)-t\bar{x}-u\bar{y})] \, dt \, du.\tag{$**$}
$$
with "integration being along admissible paths in the $t$ and $u$ planes."

Heuristically, I can see how to go from ($*$) to ($**$) by two changes of variables: $it\to t$ and $iu\to u$, but **how do I justify ($**$) rigorously? Can you please recommend (self-learning-friendly) references?**

My background: undergrad real and complex analysis. For complex analysis, I'm familiar with the Cauchy Integral Formula, Cauchy Theorem, Residue Theorem, McLauren series, contour integrals.

Comment: Sketch out the two contours as a limit of finite contours, and consider the piece needed to complete the two contours into a closed path integral. Then show that the integral over the extra piece tends to $0$ in the limit. If you somehow cannot do that, then what appears to be a change of variable may not hold. This ends up looking like a change of variable, but the apparent change of variable comes from comparing the parametrizations of two legs of the closed path. It tricks you into seeing it as a simple complex change of variable.